# ViewComponents in MVC Core and forms vs RenderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I keep hearing ViewComponents replaced RenderAction in core. However the one big thing I see missing is the ability to handle forms. It would seem ViewComponents can't do this within the view component class where as RenderAction could handle this. I understand the details as to why technically this is the case however, I am using RenderAction in .NET as (what I would refer to as a real self contained component) but the migration to Core sort of scares me because RenderAction was replaced by ViewComponent yet doesn't give the same level of functionality.

I'm just curious on what my options are when I migrate to Core with RenderAction where my "components" are handling form gets/posts. Is there any real conversion for this for Core? The only option I see is to change my component view where it specifies what controller to use and have it be dynamic to get the calling controller name via:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
```

However, this now means in every place I use this "component" I need to alter the "parent" controller to have this action method and do inside it what my RenderAction component was which seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: Where do you see the view component miss the ability to handle forms? And for you said every place you want to use the component you need alter the parent controller, just place the view page to `/Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}` folder, and the view component class can be placed any folder. Suggest you can read the official document more carefully:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0.

Comment: @Rena You can't call into a VC class via a form. It requires an actual controller/action which a VC isn't but RenderAction is. So they don't seem to be an actual replacement. However, thinking about it more I can just keep the Controller/Action I originally have as part of the "component" and have the VC view call into that, but the VC alone isn't a real replacement because of the inability to have a form post/get into a VC class like it can a Controller/Action.